# Broken CXX compiler error on cmake when building aws-sdk-cpp for iOS

Tags: ios, xcode, aws

**UPDATE:** After downloading the aws source and switched to older version 
**1.7.9** instead of **1.8**, I was able to get rid of the error for broken compiler. Now building the libs starting but I get bunch of errors like this:

```
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/include/c++/v1/cmath:313:9: error: no member
      named 'signbit' in the global namespace
using ::signbit;
```

**Before UPDATE:**

I want to build static aws libs core, s3 and transfer for iOS which i downloaded from this [link](https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-cpp). I am using macOS **High Sierra 10.13.6** and **Xcode 10.0**.

I am trying to run cmake on the source from the link with this command:

```
cmake ../aws-sdk-cpp 
-DCMAKE_C_COMPILER=clang 
-DCMAKE_C_FLAGS="-mios-version-min=11" 
-DCMAKE_CXX_COMPILER=clang++ 
-DCMAKE_CXX_FLAGS="-mios-version-min=11" 
-DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release 
-DCMAKE_OSX_SYSROOT=/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS.sdk 
-DFORCE_CURL=ON 
-DENABLE_OPENSSL_ENCRYPTION=OFF 
-DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=/Users/user/Desktop/script/lib/ios/arm64/aws-sdk-cpp 
-DCPP_STANDARD=14 
-DSIMPLE_INSTALL=ON 
-DENABLE_TESTING=OFF 
-DCMAKE_OSX_ARCHITECTURES=arm64 
-DBUILD_ONLY="core;s3;transfer" 
-DBUILD_SHARED_LIBS=OFF
```

**OUTPUT AFTER COMMAND:**

```
-- TARGET_ARCH not specified; inferring host OS to be platform compilation target

-- Building AWS libraries as static objects

-- Building project version: 1.7.330
Cross compiling third-party dependencies for architecture arm64

-- The C compiler identification is AppleClang 10.0.0.10001145

-- The CXX compiler identification is AppleClang 10.0.0.10001145

-- Check for working C compiler: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/cc

-- Check for working C compiler: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/cc -- works

-- Detecting C compiler ABI info
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info - done
-- Detecting C compile features
-- Detecting C compile features - done
-- Check for working CXX compiler: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/c++

-- Check for working CXX compiler: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/c++ -- broken

CMake Error at /usr/local/Cellar/cmake/3.12.3/share/cmake/Modules/CMakeTestCXXCompiler.cmake:45 (message):
  The C++ compiler

"/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/c++"

  is not able to compile a simple test program.

  It fails with the following output:

    Change Dir: /Users/user/Desktop/skripta/lib/ios/build/aws-sdk-cpp-iPhoneOS/aws-sdk-cpp/build/.deps/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp

    Run Build Command:"/usr/local/bin/gmake" "cmTC_a9b69/fast"
    /usr/local/bin/gmake -f CMakeFiles/cmTC_a9b69.dir/build.make CMakeFiles/cmTC_a9b69.dir/build
    gmake[1]: Entering directory '/Users/user/Desktop/skripta/lib/ios/build/aws-sdk-cpp-iPhoneOS/aws-sdk-cpp/build/.deps/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp'
    Building CXX object CMakeFiles/cmTC_a9b69.dir/testCXXCompiler.cxx.o
    /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/c++    -arch arm64 -isysroot /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS.sdk   -o CMakeFiles/cmTC_a9b69.dir/testCXXCompiler.cxx.o -c /Users/user/Desktop/skripta/lib/ios/build/aws-sdk-cpp-iPhoneOS/aws-sdk-cpp/build/.deps/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp/testCXXCompiler.cxx
    warning: include path for stdlibc++ headers not found; pass '-std=libc++' on the command line to use the libc++ standard library instead [-Wstdlibcxx-not-found]
    1 warning generated.
    Linking CXX executable cmTC_a9b69
    /usr/local/Cellar/cmake/3.12.3/bin/cmake -E cmake_link_script CMakeFiles/cmTC_a9b69.dir/link.txt --verbose=1
    /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/c++    -arch arm64 -isysroot /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS.sdk -Wl,-search_paths_first -Wl,-headerpad_max_install_names   CMakeFiles/cmTC_a9b69.dir/testCXXCompiler.cxx.o  -o cmTC_a9b69 
    clang: warning: libstdc++ is deprecated; move to libc++ with a minimum deployment target of iOS 7 [-Wdeprecated]
    ld: library not found for -lstdc++
    clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
    gmake[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/cmTC_a9b69.dir/build.make:87: cmTC_a9b69] Error 1
    gmake[1]: Leaving directory '/Users/user/Desktop/skripta/lib/ios/build/aws-sdk-cpp-iPhoneOS/aws-sdk-cpp/build/.deps/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp'
    gmake: *** [Makefile:121: cmTC_a9b69/fast] Error 2




  CMake will not be able to correctly generate this project.
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  CMakeLists.txt:7 (project)


-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
See also "/Users/user/Desktop/skripta/lib/ios/build/aws-sdk-cpp-iPhoneOS/aws-sdk-cpp/build/.deps/CMakeFiles/CMakeOutput.log".
See also "/Users/user/Desktop/skripta/lib/ios/build/aws-sdk-cpp-iPhoneOS/aws-sdk-cpp/build/.deps/CMakeFiles/CMakeError.log".
CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:229 (message):
  Failed to configure third-party libraries.


-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
```

Comment: I think we need aa fuller log t b e. Last line is not necessarily an error

Comment: @user151019 thank you for reply. I have updated my question with full log after running the command.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52441952/os-x-ld-library-not-found-for-lstdc `https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51060596/ld-library-not-found-for-lstdc-6

Comment: @ankii thank you for reply. I will check now the links. I posted update I was able to pass this broken compiler error, but however I will see if solution from the links will pass the new error too.

Comment: It looks like the aws code is old and needs to be updated to use the correct c++standard library. Go that way and not to use old xcode